# Github allow some specific non-admin users to push changes to a protected branch where all other uses have to create a pull request

Tags: github

This is for Jenkins where I don't want the Jenkins user as a Github admin but I want it to add 1 to the build number (which for iOS happens to be in the info.plist) commit + push it as part of our build process.  Adding 1 to the build number is the easy bit.

However, I generally want all users to be forced to create pull requests on this branch and have the branch as protected.

If I add the jenkins user (nickm01 below) to the "allowed to push to branch" list, that user still seems to have to create a pull request to push a commit.

How can I configure things differently?

See below for our branch settings.  Unfortunately our jenkins user "nickm01" still has to create a PR in order to push changes.

[image]

Comment: based on your description, you want your jenkins user to increment the build number following your releases.
Having to create a pull request does seem like a major and unnecessary overhead... started to do a little reading on this.
This link might help out : 
https://medium.com/salesforce-ux/infograin-plistbuddy-is-your-buddy-b969edb642ef

Comment: Adding 1 to build number is easy.  Getting those changes pushed into the branch is the problem unless I use a admin account for Jenkins, which I don't want to do.

Comment: if you are using jenkins, dont you have a dedicated git user for jenkins? i had a job resposible for releases at one workplace, where jenkins was responsible for creating release tags, definitly needed push authorization there....

Comment: Yes, have a dedicated jenkins-only git user.  But don't want that to be an admin for security reasons.

Comment: can you show the jenkins job you are using, as well as the plugins you are using ?

Comment: I'm using fastlane to update build number, commit and push.  But feel like that's beside the point - it's not a Jenkins question, it's a GitHub question

Comment: did you try running a script on jenkins in order to force push your changes to your repository ? perhaps working directly with the git commands you will be able to push your changes where fastlane fails....

Comment: Doesn't make a difference - this is a github restriction

Comment: OK. Perhaps this link is relevant ? 
https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/543

Comment: @NickMcConnell were you able to find a soultion for this issue? Running into the exact same problem with releases triggered in jenkins and don't have a solution at the moment

Comment: @Chris in the end I think I just gave Jenkins admin access